# How can I make the data cursor show the CData value in a patch plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I frequently plot spatial data in MATLAB using `patch`. Using the data cursor on the resulting plots gives the (x,y) coordinates of the nearest node. I would like to use it to give the data value at that point as well.

My assumption is that I will need to retrieve the node number that is selected, then find the appropriate value out of the CData property of the patch object. But, I don't know how to do either of those things from the scope of the datacursor update function.
So, how would I do those things? Or, is there a better way?